# Do modern versions of Solidworks still support the RunMacro method?

Tags: vba, com-interop, solidworks

SolidWorks makes a `RunMacro` method available to VBA via it's Type Library.

According to SolidWorks online help for the `RunMacro` method:

> **`ISldWorks.RunMacro`**
>
> Obsolete. Superseded by ISldWorks::RunMacro2.

And `RunMacro2` was introduced with:

> SOLIDWORKS 2009 FCS, Revision Number 17.0

I only have a copy of SolidWorks 2006, so I only have access to a type library that supports `RunMacro` and not `RunMacro2`. I've created an interop assembly from the Type Library and I'm embedding types in a C# add-in. I'm hoping that `RunMacro`, while "obsolete", is still actually usable in modern versions of SolidWorks.

Can anybody with a more recent version of SolidWorks confirm whether the `RunMacro` method is still viable?

Comment: Why not check which version of SolidWorks the user is running and use the method that corresponds to that version? See: http://help.solidworks.com/2015/english/api/sldworksapi/Get_Version_Number_Example_VB.htm for an example to retrieve the version number.

Comment: I could check the version, but if my interop assembly doesn't know about `RunMacro2` would I be able to call it?

Comment: Use the more recent version in your codebase, then version check to determine which one to use? Is your intention to only support Solidworks 2009 and older? There may be other changes pertinent in Solidworks (since '09) that may be relevant too.

Comment: The aim is to support SolidWorks 2006 and newer, but 2006 is the only version I have.

Comment: It might work for the use case you mentioned, however I think the better long term development strategy is to use one/several code bases (for SolidWorks) that will enable functionality across each version. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

All methods in SolidWorks API from earlier versions are functional in future releases to maintain any legacy code. I've always used legacy methods without problems and my version is 2016.

Answer (score 2):

An Obsolete method does not mean it's not in the software anymore, only that a newer version (usually linked when Obsolete is listed) is available. In many cases the new API calls have more features, arguments or benefit from other new features that have been added to later versions of SolidWorks.